# Count #tags in text fields (users' posts)

Tags: mysql, tags

I have a table with posts from my users. Each post is just a text field and a post can include tags, for example:

```
"Hello this is my first post and I am in #japan enjoying #tokio How are you doing?"
```

I would like to write MySQL query that would go through whole table and return most popular tags with nr of occurrences, sorted by count, for example:

```
#travel 53
#japan 14
#food 13
#tokio 6
#selfie 4
etc.
```

Note that I don't have seperate table for tags. All I have is one table with posts and #tags are part of post text.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.0, take a look at the `REGEXP_INSTR()` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` functions to find all the matches. You'll need to do this in a loop in a stored procedure, since you can't loop in SQL queries.

Comment: I am using 5.x :-(

Comment: Do you really have to do it in SQL? It's not a great language for string processing, programming languages like PHP or Python would be much easier for this.

Comment: @Barmar I am thinking of doing it in PHP, like this: each time someone adds a post, I extact # tags and save them to temporary table, each tag/word is one record, like this: tokio food toyota monkey... then i can easily count over whole table of tags and see which tags were most popular. What do you think? It won't be a big deal since I would only show tags entered in past week so I can delete old records... Thoughts?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable approach. You could also run a periodic cron job that updates the counts.

Answer (score 0):

We could do something like this:

```
SELECT v.tag
     , COUNT(1) AS cnt
  FROM ( SELECT CONCAT('#',IF(t.foo=SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,'#',i.n*-1),NULL,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,'#',i.n*-1),' ',1))) AS tag
           FROM ( SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 
                  UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
                  UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
                 ) i
           CROSS
            JOIN ( SELECT 'Hello this is my first post and I am in #japan enjoying #tokio How are you doing?' AS foo 
                   UNION ALL SELECT '#japan #rocks' 
                   UNION ALL SELECT 'a # b ## c ##'
                 ) t
         HAVING tag IS NOT NULL
       ) v
 GROUP BY v.tag
 ORDER BY cnt DESC, v.tag ASC
```

Inline view `i` needs to be extended 13, 14, 15, ... up to the maximum possible number of tags that can appear in a post.

Inline view `t` is providing some sample rows as a demonstration. The inline view should be replaced with a table reference.

We also need to specify what should be returned when strings like `#`  and `###` are encountered in the post. (Are those valid tags? Should those get counted?)

In SQL, a table reference can be replaced with an inline view.

For example, let's assume we have a table named `user_posts` that includes a character type column named `post_text`. And suppose we have this query:

```
  SELECT t.`post_text`
    FROM `user_posts` t
```

We could replace the table reference (`user_posts`) with a query that returns a resultset, like this:

```
  SELECT t.`post_text`
    FROM (
           SELECT 'Hi I''m in #tokio #japan' AS `post_text`
           UNION ALL SELECT '#hanoi #rocks'
           UNION ALL SELECT 'a # b ## c ##'
           UNION ALL SELECT ''
         ) t
```

Not that we can run that inner query standalong, separately, and have it return a resultset. When we wrapping it in parens and put it into the FROM clause of an outer query, the the result from that query are a row source for the outer query.

The query that replaces the table reference is called an "inline view". MySQL calls it a "derived table", mostly because of how the inline view gets processed in the MySQL query plan.

Comment: Well I can't put the string into query (JOIN (Select 'Hello...')) - I need a query that works without predefined values. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Maxitrol That subquery is just a placeholder for the actual table containing the data you want to search.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. That join should be: JOIN (SELECT post_text FROM users_posts) t ?

Comment: I don't get it at all. Can you write working query if my table is "users_posts" and field is "post_text"

Comment: @Maxitrol: if we want a demonstration of a working query, we might consider setting up a demonstration table with data, on a site such as SQL*Fiddle  for example like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef78de/1